# Template template argument deduction failure with GCC (works with MSVC)

Tags: c++, c++14, c++17, template-argument-deduction, template-templates

I have the following reasonably simple function template:

```
template <class OrderedSetType, template<class> class SupersetType>
OrderedSetType f(const SupersetType<OrderedSetType>& superset)
{
    return OrderedSetType();
}
```

It's called like this:

```
f(std::vector<std::string>());
```

And the compiler fails to deduce the template parameter. The diagnostic message isn't particularly helpful:

```
<source>: In function 'int main()':

<source>:12:33: error: no matching function for call to 'f(std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >)'

     f(std::vector<std::string>());

                                 ^

<source>:5:16: note: candidate: template<class OrderedSetType, template<class> class SupersetType> OrderedSetType f(const SupersetType<OrderedSetType>&)

 OrderedSetType f(const SupersetType<OrderedSetType>& superset)

                ^

<source>:5:16: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:

<source>:12:33: note:   template parameters of a template template argument are inconsistent with other deduced template arguments

     f(std::vector<std::string>());

                                 ^
```

Why does the error occur? Happens with GCC 7.3 with `-std=c++14`, does not happen with `-std=c++17`. Which changes in the C++ 17 standard allowed for this code to compile? And can I make it compile for C++14?

Here's the live demo: https://godbolt.org/g/89BTzz

Specifying the template arguments explicitly doesn't help, by the way.

P. S. In the meantime, MSVC has no problems with this piece of code, but clang 5 and 6 cannot compile it even in C++17 mode. So either clang has a bug and fails to compile standard-compliant code, or GCC has a bug and successfully compiles code that it shouldn't (with `-std=c++17`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with

```
template <template <typename...> class SupersetType,
          typename FirstT, typename ... OthersTs>
FirstT f (SupersetType<FirstT, OthersTs...> const & superset)
 { return FirstT{}; }
```

or also

```
template <template <typename...> class SupersetType, typename FirstT>
FirstT f (SupersetType<FirstT> const & superset)
 { return FirstT{}; }
```

The problem is that `std::vector` doesn't accept only a type but two; the second is an allocator with a default value.

So you have to take in count this problem.

Obviously you can write `f()` with a template-template parameter that accept only two types

```
template <template <typename, typename> class SupersetType,
          typename FirstT, typename SecondT>
FirstT f (SupersetType<FirstT, SecondT> const & superset)
 { return FirstT{}; }
```

but if you use a template parameter that accept a variadic list of types, you have a more flexible `f()` (that match more containers)

Comment: Ugh, the allocator strikes again. I keep forgetting about it. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

> Which changes in the C++ 17 standard allowed for this code to compile?

You're declaring the template template parameter `SupersetType` contaning only one template parameter, but the [template template argument](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters#Template_template_arguments) `std::vector<std::string>` has two, i.e. `std::string` and the default template argument `std::allocator<string>`. Before C++17 they don't match and leads to error (then you have to make them match to solve the issue), since C++17 ([CWG 150](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#150)) it's allowed; i.e. the default template arguments are allowed for a template template argument to match a template template parameter with fewer template parameters.

> ```
> template<class T> class A { /* ... */ };
> template<class T, class U = T> class B { /* ... */ };
> template <class ...Types> class C { /* ... */ };
>
> template<template<class> class P> class X { /* ... */ };
> X<A> xa; // OK
> X<B> xb; // OK in C++17 after CWG 150
>          // Error earlier: not an exact match
> X<C> xc; // OK in C++17 after CWG 150
>          // Error earlier: not an exact match
> ```

Comment: So, the change allowed the compiler to treat `B` as if it only has one template parameter (because the other one has a default value)?

Comment: @VioletGiraffe Yes.

Answer (score 1):

While this doesn't provide an answer to your problem, it provide an alternative.

Remember that all standard container have a public type named `value_type`. That means you could easily skip the template template and only have something like

```
template<typename ContainerT>
typename ContainerT::value_type f(ContainerT const& superset)
{
    return typename ContainerT::value_type();
}
```

As long as your `SupersetType` follows the standard containers with a `value_type` member, it should work.

Comment: Good point, but I wanted it to be more generic and support containers that have only `begin()` / `end()` and don't necessarily define `value_type`.